# I'm trying to create toggle button by adding and removing active class that I've already styled but it wasn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I kept getting the following error as I click each button. I think my selector is correct. I can't figure out why Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement. (xx.js:55)

```js
const activateButtons = () => {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]');
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            button.parentdNode.classList.add('active');

            buttons.forEach(otherButton => {
                if (otherButton !== button) {
                    otherButton.parentNode.classList.remove('active');
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
activateButtons()
```

```css
.btn{
    color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
    border: 1px solid #007bff;
    padding:10px;
    
}
input[type="radio"]{
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
       appearance: none;
}
.active{
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!--//button-->
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" style="margin-bottom: 1rem">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary active" >
            <input type="radio" name="source"  autocomplete="off" checked> Button A
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="source"  autocomplete="off" >  Button B
        </label>
    </div>
    <!--//button-->
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove active class from all other buttons upon clicking another button?

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `button.parentdNode.classList.add('active');` You have `parentdNode` instead of `parentNode`

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled parentNode, writing parentdNode

Comment: While this answers the question, typo answers are generally frowned upon - especially since I already left a comment.